# How to load an ImageView by URL(json output) in Android?

Tags: android, json, image

url to display the image.
I already displayed the 'text' contents
using the following code

```
protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {
 if (dialog.isShowing()) {
dialog.dismiss();
 }
 ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(context, jsonlist,
 R.layout.list_item, new String[] { ID, TITLE,
  LOGO}, new int[] {
  R.id.flyer_id, R.id.title, R.id.logo
   });
 setListAdapter(adapter);
lv = getListView();   
  }
```

Comment: use custom adapter and AsyncTask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try loading images using lazy loading concept.There is a good example mentioned in github.
Try this link 
https://github.com/thest1/LazyList